# Can linked list store data permanently?

Tags: c

I'm newbie on c programming. I am assigned to make a library program with linked list. question is can linked list store data if I terminate the program or do I need to store it within files, so I can still access it later? I've googled it but still no answers.

Comment: You need to store the list in a file. And you can't store pointers in the file, so you need to deal with that.

Comment: Linked list won't store data in a non-volatile storage on its own, you'll have to write code to store the data on non-volatile storage(eg: file, database) and retrieve it after a reset/reboot of a program.

Comment: @user3386109 is right, you cannot store pointers so, I think you'll need to read data from file and create a linked list

Comment: Linked lists are stored in memory, and memory is released when your program ends or the computer is shut down. If you need it to remain available after either of those, you have to provide a way to store it yourself.